# Constructing a pentagon from a circle

Tags: trigonometry, geometry

To my understanding you can create any regular N sided shape by using a circle. I decided to give this an attempt from the equations/ formulas given from the internet.

[image]

Just a side note - is it worth learning Unit Circle if I were to develop my trigonometry skills?

The circle of the radius is 1, thus we can determine an equal distance of space between each points. For example if `N = (2PI/3)` visually N will have an equal distance between them?

When it comes to mapping out the `X` and `Y` coordinates, I used the equation `x = cos(N*P)` and `y = Sin(N*P)`

From doing this calculation I mapped out the points and this was the finished result.
[image]

Does this regular pentagon look how it should look opposed to a regular pentagon, if yes, then did I do something wrong in my maths? `P = (2PI/5)` did give a big floating point number that I had rounded up to two decimal places.

If the equations provided above are correct, can it be human error of the mapping points?

Another question, how can this be converted into maths notation?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Something is definitely off here:  the points p2 and p3 should be *symmetric* with respect to the $x$ axis, but p2 is about $4$ ticks up whereas p3 is almost $6$ ticks down.

Comment: @JackM It's a two part, one is the pentagon constructed properly, and two if I calculate the vertices with bigger floating point numbers, will my mapping become much more precise?

Comment: Your calculation has a problem. The accuracy of the calculation of the sin/cos of 2 decimal would be enough (single precision floating point is great). You have a bias (negative foe which you need to find the source) which is noticeable even in $P_5$, which is (0,1)